# File types inside rpm file

Tags: linux, rpm

Is there any way to get file types (or more exactly, list of binaries) from rpm package file without unpacking it? It's assumed that there is a rpm file which isn't installed and we need just to learn file types inside it.

Comment: "rpm -qlp file.rpm" shows all the files inside rpm, I need binaries only or, more generally, file types.

Comment: @olegst: RPM does not store "file types". You can get a list of file names or you can extract the files using rpm2cpio and analyze them.

Answer (score 3):

not sure if that answers your question, but you can view file permissions inside a package

if package installed:

```
rpm -qlv package-name.rpm
```

if not installed:

```
rpm -qlvp package-name.rpm
```

typical output might be:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user     size  date filename
```

the `x` will indicate if a file is executable but also that a directory can be traversed...

Answer (score 0):

There used to be "[kpackage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KPackage)", but AFAIK it has not been ported to KDE4...

Currently i only know that you can use the rpm command directly with its command line options. Most package handlers offer similar options, for example zypper and yum.